# How to set margin & font size while converting tex to pdf?

Tags: pdf, emacs

I'm trying to make a PDF book out of a Github tutorial at https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/guide-en.org (to read it comfortably on my iPad) To do that, I exported the Emacs org file into a tex file and converted it into a pdf by:

```
$ pandoc -s emacs-in-one-year.tex -o emacs-in-one-year.pdf
```

and it got converted but the resulting PDF looked out of proportions; the fonts were quite small and there were huge margins on four sides of the texts. For a screenshot see: https://i.hizliresim.com/kXdlp9.png

I've searched Stackoverflow for this problem and applied the suggested solutions but none of them ever worked, the margins are still huge and fonts are small. The modified tex file looks like below now. How can I make fonts larger and margins smaller? Thanks.

```
% Created 2017-12-04 Mon 18:08
\documentclass[13pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1cm}{1cm}{*} % Left and right margin
\setulmarginsandblock{2cm}{2cm}{*}  % Upper and lower margin
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a4paper,
  margin=10pt,
 includeheadfoot
}
\tolerance=1000
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\author{REPL & The Code Maker}
\date{\today}
\title{Emacs in one year}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 25.2.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section*{Master Emacs in one year \hfill{}\textsc{emacs:en}}
\label{sec-1}
Author: Chen Bin (redguardtoo)

Version: 20150424

Updated: \textit{<2015-04-24 Fri>}

Created: \textit{[2012-01-31 Tue 15:08]}

Copyright: This work is licensed under the         
 \href{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/}{Creative Commons     Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 3.0 Unported License}.

\subsection*{Introduction}
\label{sec-1-1}
I was a Microsoft fan because I was born in China. There was no Unix     culture when I was young.
```

When I convert

Comment: it is hard to comment on the layout of your example as it produces multiple errors starting with `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \setlrmarginsandblock` so doesn't really make any usable output at all.

Comment: the setlrmargins commands come from memoir but you are not loading that class, but you are setting the page size via those commands, by `fullpage` and by `geometry`  just do _one_ of those (and if you use memoir load that class)  article class does not have a 13pt option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your example to run without error and have I think the margins that you intended (but these margins are *much* too small).

```
% Created 2017-12-04 Mon 18:08
\documentclass[
% there is no 13pt option so 13pt wouldgive 10pt 
12pt,
a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% do not use\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% use geometry instead \usepackage{fullpage}

% memoir only \setlrmarginsandblock{1cm}{1cm}{*} % Left and right margin
% memoir only \setulmarginsandblock{2cm}{2cm}{*}  % Upper and lower margin
% memoir only  \checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a4paper,
  margin=10pt, % are you sure you want margins that small?????
               % that will not print on may home printers and will make a text block
               % too wide to read with comfort
 includeheadfoot
}
\tolerance=1000
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
%\author{REPL & The Code Maker}
% \and not &
\author{REPL \and The Code Maker}

\date{\today}
\title{Emacs in one year}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 25.2.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section*{Master Emacs in one year \hfill{}\textsc{emacs:en}}
\label{sec-1}
Author: Chen Bin (redguardtoo)

Version: 20150424

Updated: \textit{<2015-04-24 Fri>}

Created: \textit{[2012-01-31 Tue 15:08]}

Copyright: This work is licensed under the         
 \href{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/}
      {Creative Commons     Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 3.0 Unported License}.

\subsection*{Introduction}
\label{sec-1-1}
I was a Microsoft fan because I was born in China. There was no Unix culture when I was young.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP might want such small margins, if the document will be viewed on a hand-held device.

Comment: @RobtAll well perhaps, but then it shouldn't say a4paper (unless you have big hands:-)

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for the interest. I haven't included the whole tex file as it was bit long. I have remade it from scratch (includes no modifications of mine) https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz47m7ua4rvihpp/emacs-in-one-year.tex?dl=0 

I've tried converting the file you've edited but the result's almost the same, i.e. the margins are huge and fonts are small : ( Maybe it would be better to try with the unmodified tex file.

Comment: Yep, I read the books on an iPad, so the smaller the margins the better. Tex seems to have the margins quite large by default.

Comment: @Romario it isn't that the margins are large by design it's that A4 (and US letter) are too wide for single column text at normal font sizes so a single column text format on A4 ends up with wide margins. on a digital medium it's more or less equivalent leave the font size at 10pt but specify a small page size (and small margins) using geometry.

Comment: @Romario it isn't necessary to post a large document or use external links but you should make sure that the document that you do add to the question actually shows the issue.  (the code in your question makes no pdf at all as posted)

Comment: Hello thank you for the comment. If you mean the pandoc command line doesn't make any pdf at all, then I must say that it does make pdf on my OS X Lion computer, pandoc didn't work on your computer, perhaps?

Comment: I might give it a try, i.e.  specifying a small page size and small margins using geometry. My aim is to make the page look comfortable on iBooks app on iPad.